# How to map an XML schema to an OpenCalc spreadsheet cell and export cell data as an XML data file

Tags: openoffice.org

I have created an XML schema for storing data. I want to provide a simple user interface with OpenCalc spreadsheet for data entry.

Things which I wanted to do.

1. Map my XML schema elements to cells of a spreadsheet.
2. Provide this spreadsheet as an user interface for data entry.
3. Export the entered data as an XML data file. (The exported XML data file should have the tag elements defined in the XML schema mapped to the appropriate data entered by the user)

About the XML schema:

1. None of the schema elements have attributes.
2. The XML schema has repeating elements. i.e , An element can be present more than one time in the XML data file.

Is it possible to do this in OpenCalc?